# How do I access the AST (abstract syntax tree) for a PL/SQL stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql

When Oracle compiles a stored procedure, it stores the AST for the procedure in DIANA format.

- how can I access this AST?
- are there built-in tools for processing this AST?

Comment: I've not come across the abbreviation AST before.  The only time I've seen anything about DIANA is in the PL/SQL Program Limits section of the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/limits.htm which talks about how PL/SQL uses a variant of DIANA and an Interface Definition Language (IDL).  Why would you want to access or process this?  I don't know of any way to access it though I'm sure you probably could find some combination of `x$` tables and block dumps to look at it if you're really determined.  But there is probably an easier way to get whatever you need.

Comment: [How about `SYS.IDL_xxx$`?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_pc.htm)

Comment: Alexandre Porcelli has published [an 11gR2 PL/SQL Parser for Antlr](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser) on Github.  Obviously not built-in, and probably not complete, but perhaps it will suit your needs.

Answer (score 9):

There is an undocumented package DUMPDIANA that is meant to dump the Diana in a human-readable format.

The file $ORACLE_HOME\rdbms\admin\dumpdian.sql says "Documentation is available in /vobs/plsql/notes/dumpdiana.txt". I cannot find that file, and without it we can only guess at the meaning of some parameters. Basic usage of DUMPDIANA is as follows:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> @?\rdbms\admin\dumpdian

Library created.


Package created.


Package body created.

create or replace procedure hello_world
  2  as
  3  begin
  4  dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
  5* end;


Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> execute sys.DUMPDIANA.dump('HELLO_WORLD');
user: SYS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

At this point a pair of files should have been created in the folder 
`$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/orcl12c/orcl12c/trace`. The two files seem to follow the naming convention:

```
orcl12c_ora_{PROCESS}.trc
orcl12c_ora_{PROCESS.trm
```

Where the trc file is a human readable version of the corresponding trm file, and {PROCESS} is the operating system process ID. To find this use the following query from the same session:

```
select p.spid from v$session s,v$process p 
where s.paddr = p.addr
and s.sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID');
```

For example if the session ID was 8861 then from a bash shell you can view the results using:

```
vim $ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/orcl12c/orcl12c/trace/orcl12c_ora_8861.trc
```

The result is interesting... if not particularly intuitive! For example here is a snippet of the file produced. Note the HELLO_WORLD string literal.

```
PD1(2):D_COMP_U  [
    L_SRCPOS : row 1 col 1
    A_CONTEX :
PD2(2):      D_CONTEX  [
          L_SRCPOS : row 1 col 1
          AS_LIST :  < >
      ]
    A_UNIT_B :
PD3(2):      D_S_BODY  [
          L_SRCPOS : row 1 col 1
          A_D_ :
PD4(2):            DI_PROC  [
                L_SRCPOS : row 1 col 11
                L_SYMREP : HELLO_WORLD,
                S_SPEC : PD5^(2),
                S_BODY : PD8^(2),
```

A couple of notes. I've run this as SYS, which as we know is not a good practice, this is no reason I know of why you shouldn't grant privileges on DUMPDIANA to a normal user. All the procedures you dump go into the same file - if you delete that file, it stops working, and you'll need to start a new session. If it stops working, starting a new session sometimes seems to fix the problem.

Comment: @jon-heller Thanks for your edit. After a few (or a lot), of guesses I found out it dumps out the data to a file, which is kind of annoying as it makes it difficult to further process the data inside the db. We could read it back in using an external table, and then do some kind of parsing on it, or maybe dumpdiana is the wrong track and there is some other way to get the AST in a more relational friendly format.

Comment: This update definitely answers the question.  Unfortunately the results are still probably too cryptic to be useful.  I'll let the bounty stay open for a few days to see if anyone can improve on it.

Comment: For anyone else that is researching this:This document http://www.dtic.mil/docs/citations/ADA272792, which looks to have come straight from the Mad Men props cupboard, describes the DIANA language in some detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent tutorial on DIANA and IDL in the PDF [How to unwrap PL/SQL](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-06/BH-US-06-Finnigan.pdf) by Pete Finnigan, principal consultant at Siemens at the time of the writting, specializing in researching and securing Oracle databases.

Among other very interesting things you will learn that:

- DIANA is written down as IDL (Interface Definition Language).
- The 4 tables the IDL is stored in (IDL_CHAR$, IDL_SB4$, IDL_UB1$ and IDL_UB2$)
- Wrapper PL/SQL is simply DIANA written down as IDL.
- Dumpdiana is not installed by default, you need to ensure DIANA, PIDL, and DIUTIL PL/SQL packages are installed as well and you need to run it as SYS.
- How to dump the DIANA tree and understand it.
- How to reconstruct the PL/SQL source from DIANA.
- How to write a PL/SQL un-wrapper.
- Limitations of a PL/SQL API based un-wrapper.
- Limitations of the PL/SQL API itself.
- How to enumerate DIANA nodes and attributes.
- A proof of concept un-wrapper.

You can find [his website here](http://www.petefinnigan.com/). There is so much content there. You will find [awesome papers about Oracle security](http://www.petefinnigan.com/orasec.htm) and also a lot of [useful security tools](http://www.petefinnigan.com/tools.htm) developed not only by him but other authors as well.

Best of all, you can get in touch with him if after the reading you still have questions.

Comment: This is some useful theoretical information but it seems hundreds of hours of work away from a practical solution.