# Get the compiled output of a SQL package

Tags: sql, database, oracle, compilation, oracle19c

I want to get the compiled output of a SQL file. Like the `.class` file for Java. How I can do that.

I am using Oracle 19c

Comment: What would you do with this "compiled output" (and/or what problem are you trying to solve by getting compiled output)?  There really isn't the equivalent of a .class file for PL/SQL.  If you are trying to give someone a package they can install on their system without them being able to easily view the source code, you can use the wrap utility to encrypt the code (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/c_wrap.htm) realizing that, just like with a .class file being decompiled, the wrap process is pretty reversable.

Comment: @JustinCave I want to get the number of basic blocks inside a PL/SQL package. I can do this with DBMS_PLSQL_CODE_COVERAGE package. But unfortunately, I can't deploy this PL/SQL file to the database. So I'm trying to get the number of basic blocks in some explicit way.  At the moment I am not 100% sure whether I can get this from a compiled output. But basic blocks are separated from the jump statements as far as I know. That's why I am looking for a way to get the compiled output of a PL/SQL file.

Comment: I don't think you can get there from here.  You'd need to deploy the package to the database server in order for it to be compiled.  Once it is deployed and compiled, it is converted into DIANA, a tree-structured intermediate language, and machine-readable m-code.  I cannot imagine how you would get from DIANA or m-code to PL/SQL basic blocks.

Comment: Thanks, @JustinCave. According to the oracle `A basic block is a linear segment of code with no branches. A basic block has a single entry point (no code within a basic block is the destination of a jump instruction) and a single exit point (only the last instruction, or an exception, can move the point of execution to a different basic block). Basic block boundaries cannot be predicted by visual inspection of the code. The compiler generates the blocks that are executed at runtime.`  So I thought if I get the compiled output of a PL/SQL file I can find it out manually?

Comment: But the compiler only compiles something when you deploy it to the database.  If you can deploy the code to the database, you'd just use the `dbms_plsql_code_coverage` package.  And without having access to Oracle's internal documentation, I don't see how you'd convert DIANA or m-code to PL/SQL basic blocks.  That would be a ton of reverse engineering work.

Comment: @BuddhikaChathuranga See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35180348/409172) for how to print the DIANA nodes for a package. The [`DUMPDIANA`](https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/pkgs/dumpdiana.html) package also contains a function `NODE_COUNT` that might do what you want, but I couldn't get that procedure to work for me on 19c. These kind of advanced PL/SQL compilation questions rarely get a good answer since the compiler is closed source and there's just not that much information available about how it works.

Comment: Thank you @JonHeller  Then I guess deploying the package to the DB would be the better approach.